# If it is even possible, how do I apply the "-32bitclient" command to a directory in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, nfs

I'm running the older 10.6.8 on a computer, and in order to use the software installed on it, I need to keep it in 64-bit mode. However, in order to download files off a particular media card, I need a 32-bit folder. I know nfs manager allows you to create a folder with an option called “Enforce 32-bit folder cookies although NFSv3 requires 64-bits." I figured it must be possible then to recreate that in Terminal.

Help?

Comment: I feel like your question isn't very clear. How is NFS involved here? Is there more than one machine? Which one's the server and which is the client? Which one is the media card connected to?

Comment: I'll try to elaborate. http://www.bandpro.com/blog/how-to-setup-the-sony-sr-pc4-for-ethernet-transfer/ is the link to the tutorial I've been trying to follow. But, with the older OS and the fact that my company did not want to purchase the NFS Manager software, I thought I could do the same thing via Terminal as the option within the software "Enforce 32-bit folder cookies although NFSv3 requires 64-bits" in step 8 under heading: Ethernet File Transfer Setup.

Comment: Okay, so your 10.6.8 Mac is the 64-bit NFS server, and this Sony memory card reader box is the 32-bit NFS client. The Sony box mounts the NFS export from the Mac and then pushes the video files (or whatever) to the Mac.

BTW, why even bother with NFS? The user manual for that Sony box says it supports CIFS (which is also known as "SMB" or "Windows File Sharing"). Why not just enable Windows File Sharing in the Sharing panel of OS X and have the Sony box connect via CIFS?

Comment: That sounds like it would be worth a shot. I guess I just got caught up with trying to hack the tutorial. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your setup fully from the way you phrased your question, but the answer is probably that **you need to edit `/etc/exports` to add `-32bitclients` to the entry for that exported directory.**

If you're really new to the Terminal, I should probably mention that `/etc/exports`  is a text-based NFS configuration file that specifies how you want to export (share) various directories via NFS. You probably have to have superuser (root) privileges to edit it, so you could edit it with, say, `sudo vi /etc/exports` (if you know `vi`).

See the manual page for `exports(5)` (that is, run `man exports` or `man 5 exports`) for more information on the format and options of `/etc/exports`